# I'm not receiving remote data message when my app is in background

Tags: swift, firebase

I have setup up my app to receive data messages, which works well in foreground but when the app is in background nothing happens. 
Here is my payload. I need the phone awakened(if its in background) when the notification is received. I have done my research online and I can't find the answer please help me.

Here is my payload

```
    {
 "to" : "xxxxx",
 "data" : {
     "body" : "Hey?",
     "title": "CHill"
 }
}
```

Comment: on what way would you expect the _payload_ arriving into your app? casual network request? via remote notification? via streaming?

Comment: via remote notification

Comment: is that supposed to be part of a _silent-notification_?

Comment: No it's not, because I need the phone to be awakened when the notification is sent

Comment: in that case you can get the _payload_ __only__ when the user opens the application from the notification, until that the app in the background (or if terminated) will have no knowledge about the notifications.